# Interfacing Google Doc Api's with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, powerpoint, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to interface with the Google Docs APIs, namely the Google Documents List Data API v3.0.
Are there any open-source Ruby libraries that can do the interfacing? Google has a Python api released for v3.0; I'm looking for something similar.

(I'm trying to develop a webapp that converts from PowerPoint to a Google doc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [gdata](http://rubygems.org/gems/gdata) gem? I'm not sure it helps, but it has a number of clients for working with Google Data APIs, namely the [DocList](http://gdata-ruby-util.googlecode.com/hg/doc/classes/GData/Client/DocList.html)...